# React 4.0.0 BrowserRouter rendering all Routes

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I am trying to make a simple texting app with user registration with react and meteor and when I try to add routes as so:

```
**//main.js**
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
import {Tracker} from "meteor/tracker";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import {Texts} from "./../imports/api/Text";
import App from "./../imports/ui/App";
import Name from "./../imports/ui/Name";
import NotFound from "./../imports/ui/NotFound"

Meteor.startup(() => {
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
        let texts = Texts.find().fetch();
        console.log(texts);
        console.log(browserHistory);
        const routes = (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Route path="/chat" render={()=>{
                        return <App texts={texts} />
                    }}/>
                    <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
        ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById("app"));
    });
});


**//NotFound.js**
import React from "react";

export default class NotFound extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <p>URL not found</p>
    }
}
```

it renders both things to the screen, I see my error 404 text, and my texting app.  My problem is, how do I get the NotFound page to render when the Route is not recognized(ex. "/asddkib") and make it go away(just the app) when I go to the right path ("/chat")?  Right now if I go to /chat then both get rendered to the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use switch statement

```
 import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom', 
 <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <App path="/chat" texts={texts}/>
                <Route  component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Still no result, do I remove the <div></div> for the switch? Or do I add the switch with the div?

Comment: Thanks!!! So if I was to make new pages, would I have to make a <Route /> or the component name like you did with <App />

Comment: You can use any option 
<Route path="/path"  component={Componet}/>
or
<Componet path="/path" />

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for react router's switch functionality.

Change your import from "react-router" to this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom',
```

Then, add the Switch component into your render:

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/chat" render={()=>{
                return <App texts={texts} />
            }}/>
            <Route  component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I have that and still does not work.....Is there something wrong with my NotFound.js?(updated above)

Comment: I realized I had lowercase "switch" component, you need to use uppercase Switch? I have updated the code.

Comment: Can you show the code in your NotFound component? (Add it to the answer and reply back here)